# AS3 - Chinese text and system fonts

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

If I set an input textfield to use a _sans system font, does it display Chinese characters?

Thanks.
Uli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue will be whether the system that is running your swf has a Chinese font installed.

_sans is the default 'sans serif' font installed on the system.

Typically PC's in China will ;), Mac's also have one installed by default.

This is a multi lingual presentation that pulls in text from an XML file. If I play this on my Mac and choose the Chinese option I see the font. If I run it on my UK based Windows XP machine it doesn't display the font. The swf specifies the _sans font for anything other than latin languages. So Russian also uses the _sans font.

http://www.sita.aero/content/intelligent-airport-vision

You could assume that people wanting to read information in Chinese would have a Chinese font installed on their system, therefore specifying _sans would be a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I guess this works also for Japanese, Korean and Hindu, right? I think I'll it should work if I build a language detection and switch my textfields to a system font if it's not a latin language.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. It would be beneficial if you had access to systems which used those languages, for testing purposes.

Comment: That is a problem I need to fix. I've no idea how to manage that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to be concerned about using a Unicode font (one that has chinese glyphs in it, think you can use the character map program in windows to browse the glyphs in a font).  I haven't actually had to do localization for China ever so I'm not positive, but here's the wiki page on unicode fonts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font.

Comment: Ah didn't realize you literally meant the font name is _sans, crooksy88's answer sounds more on point.